# Como actualizar el delegado de un QTableView desde un Hilo

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Me gustaría saber si saben como hacer que se actualice una barra de progreso, que está dibujada utilizando un Delegado, la clase se llama QAbstractItemDelegate, esta clase la sobreescribi para dibujar un QWidget en especifico una barra de progreso QProgressBar, utilice un QMainWindow como contenedor principal, en el cual hay un QListView y un QStandarItemModel, mas a parte un boton, al dar click al boton llama a una funcion que usa un clase hilo de QThread en el cual, en el metodo run establesco un contador, el cual me gustaria que se actualizara en el QListView que a su ves tiene un QAbstractItemDelegate mencionado anterior arriba, que dibuja la barra de progreso, el contador funciona pero la barra de progreso se actualiza solo cuando doy click en el QlistView. Estoy utilizando PyQt 5.4.1, dejo el codigo fuente.

Les mando un cordial saludo, espero me halla explicado bien.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Delegado(QAbstractItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Delegado, self).__init__()

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        estilo = "QProgressBar#barraDelegado{border: 0px solidgrey; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; color: grey; font-weight: bold;} "
        estilo += "QProgressBar#barraDelegado::chunk {background-color: #CD96CD;}"
        f = open("../css/estilos.css")

        barra = QProgressBar()
        barra.setObjectName("barraDelegado")
        value = index.data()
        barra.resize(option.rect.size())
        barra.setMinimum(0)
        barra.setMaximum(100)
        barra.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        barra.setValue(int(value))
        if barra.value() < 51:
            barra.setStyleSheet(estilo)
        elif barra.value() > 50 and barra.value() < 100:
            barra.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar#barraDelegado{font-weight: bold; border: 0px solidgrey; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; color: white} QProgressBar#barraDelegado::chunk {background-color: orange; color:red;}")
        elif barra.value() > 99:
            barra.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar#barraDelegado{font-weight: bold; border: 0px solidgrey; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; color: white} QProgressBar#barraDelegado::chunk {background-color: lightgreen; color:red;}")

        painter.save()
        painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft())
        barra.render(painter)
        painter.restore()
        f.close()

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.slider = QSlider(parent)
        self.slider.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.slider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        # slider.installEventFilter(self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        #print("return slider")

        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.imprime)
        return self.slider

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
        print("update geometry")

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        #print("editor data")
        #value = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        editor.setValue(int(index.data()))


    def setModelData(self, widget, model, index):
        print("columna: {0} Fila: {1}".format(index.column(), index.row()))
        model.setData(model.index(index.row(), 1), str(widget.value()), Qt.DisplayRole)
        value = widget.value()
        widget.setToolTip(str(value))
        print(widget.value())
        #self.modelo.setData(self.modelo.index(0, 1), str(progress), Qt.DisplayRole)
    def imprime(self, valor):
        self.slider.setToolTip(str(valor))
        print(valor)

class Hilo(QThread):

    def __init__(self, modelo, tabla, delegado):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.tabla = tabla
        self.Delegate = delegado

    def __del__(self):
        print("Fruncion __del__")
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 100):
            time.sleep(0.3)  # artificial time delay
            #self.emit(SIGNAL('update(QString)'), "from work thread " + str(i))
            self.modelo.setData(self.modelo.index(0, 1), str(i), Qt.DisplayRole)
            self.tabla.update()
            #self.tabla.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, self.Delegate)
            print("ejemplo {0}".format(i))
        return
   def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("saliendo..")
        try:
            self.t._stop()
        except:
            pass
        print("Salido")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = window()
    obj.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Esta es la imagen de muestra en donde la primer linea es la que estoy manipulando con el código]

Comment: ¿Qué es window?, ¿QListView o QTableView?

Comment: Hola eyllanesc, gracias por darte el tiempo de responder a mi pregunta, espero contestar a las dos preguntas, el "window" es una clase que sobre escribi, para interceptar el cierre de la venta y así cerrar el hilo que se estuviese ejecutando, pasa que antes lo intente con threads de python. En cuanto al ListView o TableView, para mi son las vistas, en qt.

Comment: Hola moises, te funciono mi solución?

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar un [mcve] para la siguiente ocasion ya que asi ahorramos tiempo(no construimos la aplicacion desde cero) y nos centramos en el problema central :P

Comment: Hola eyllanesc, como estas, me dio un error que dice: RuntimeError: QMetaObject.invokeMethod() call failed, no se a que se deva. Devo reconocer que sabes mucho de progracion en qt, muchas gracias por tu correccion, un saludo.

Comment: Que version de PyQt5 estas usando?

Comment: ¿Te genera ese error al ejecutar mi ejemplo?

Comment: Hola es la version 5.4.1 y uso python 3.4.

Comment: Si me genera el siguente error RuntimeError: QMetaObject.invokeMethod() call failed, gracias eyllanesc.

Comment: si me parece bien, solo dame unos minutos para instalarlo, se puede pasar al chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una regla básica de Qt es que no se debe actualizar la GUI desde un hilo secundario directamente, y al usar el método setData() lo estas haciendo por lo que ello estas generando que no se actualice el modelo correctamente.

Para poder actualizar la GUI debemos enviar la data al hilo principal, una forma de hacerlo es a traves de señales, pero una forma mucho más sencilla es usar QMetaObject.invokeMethod, este invoca a los metodos, para ello debemos indicarle que el tipo de conexión es de tipo Qt.QueuedConnection, esto indica que se comunicara entre hilos.

```
class Hilo(QThread):
    def __init__(self, modelo, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.modelo = modelo

    def __del__(self):
        print("Fruncion __del__")
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 100):
            time.sleep(0.3)  # artificial time delay
            import random 
            row = random.randint(0, self.modelo.rowCount()-1)
            ix = self.modelo.index(row, 1)
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.modelo,
                "setData", Qt.QueuedConnection, 
                Q_ARG(QModelIndex, ix), 
                Q_ARG(QVariant, str(i)))
            print("ejemplo {0}".format(i))
```

No es necesario ni correcto pasarle la vista ni el delegado.

Un ejemplo completo lo puedes encontrar en el siguiente [enlace](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/283c9bf900e029510b47f991422ffb3a).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me fue de mucha utilidad.